# Controlling Multiple Embed Videos In A Single Page

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed

I have multiple embed videos from different sites (Youtube,Vimeo, Dailymotion etc..) on a single page. I would like to give the user a central control panel similar to any desktop media player with pause, play, next video, prev video and volume control.

How can i achieve this ? Is it even possible ? I know Youtube has an api but what about other websites ? Is there a common API for all of them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sumanP/rzeb23aq/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>


    var player1st;
    var player2nd;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
    player1st = new YT.Player('frame1st', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); 
    player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});
        }


    //function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player2nd = new YT.Player('frame2nd', {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}}); }


    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert(event.target.getPlayerState());

    }

</script>






<iframe id="frame1st" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1g30Xyh6Wqc?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.playVideo(); return false">play1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.pauseVideo(); return false">pause1st</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player1st.stopVideo(); return false">stop1st</a>




<iframe id="frame2nd" style="position: relative; height: 220px; width: 400px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T39hYJAwR40?rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe><br>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.playVideo(); return false">play2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.pauseVideo(); return false">pause2nd</a><br>
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="player2nd.stopVideo(); return false">stop2nd</a>
```